# Cannot install python gpg on Kali

Tags: kali-linux, python, gpg

I am unable to install gpg with pip:

```
# pip install gpg
Collecting gpg
  Downloading 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Could not find gpgme-config.  Please install the libgpgme development package.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QzenGe/gpg/
```

Trying to install `libgpgme` or `libgpgme-dev` leads to

```
# pip install libgpgme
Collecting libgpgme
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libgpgme (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libgpgme
```

**How can I install gpg despite the fact that there is no version for my distribution?**

---

**PS**:

I am running on Kali 4.6.0:

```
# uname -a
Linux hostname 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The `libgpgme` _development_ package is called `libgpgme-dev`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: libgpgme is not a Python package. It should be a .deb package, so you should install it with the operating system's package management tools, not with Python-specific `pip`. My first guess would be `apt-get install libgpgme libgpgme-dev`. Once that is successfully completed, you can use `pip install gpg` to install the Python gpg package. (Note: the Python `gpg` package is for using GPG within Python programs. There is also a .deb package with the same name, which contains the `gpg` command-line tool.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need `gpgme-config`, you’ll need to install `libgpgme-dev`, which is the development package for `libgpgme`:

```
apt install libgpgme-dev
```

You could also skip using `pip` entirely and install the `python-gpg` (or `python3-gpg` if you’re using Python 3) package instead:

```
apt install python-gpg
```

Comment: I have the same error with `pip install libgpgme-dev`: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement livgpgme-dev (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for livgpgme-dev`

Comment: `libgpgme-dev` isn’t a `pip` module, it’s a Debian/Kali package; you need to use `apt` to install it. (`sudo apt install libgpgme-dev`.)

Comment: This was `sudo yum install gpgme-devel` on Alma 9, in case that's helpful for someone.